# Django import export Line number: 1 - u"Column 'id' not found

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, django-import-export

I am trying to import excel documents into a Django DB. I have added the following code to `admin.py` and `model.py`. There seems to be an error in the development of Django. I have read through several different documentations about how to fix this error. But I am still a little lost on how to implement it exactly.

In the Trace it keeps saying that my excel document needs an `id` field. There is no `id` field in my excel docs nor did I tell my model to look for an `id` field.

The documentation that I have found states that I should use `get_or_init_instance` here:

> https://django-import-export.readthedocs.org/en/latest/import_workflow.html

Any help that you guys could give would be great.

admin.py

```
class VinCasesAndCampaignsResource(resources.ModelResource):
    published = fields.Field(column_name='published_date')

    def get_instance(self, instance_loaders, row):
        return False

    class Meta:
        model = VinCasesAndCampaigns
        widgets = {}
        fields = ('VIN','LatestOpenCaseID','LatestClosedCaseID', 
                  'OpenDate', 'CloseDate', 'HasCampaigns',)
        import_id_fields = ['VIN']
        export_order = ('VIN',)
        exclude = ('id')
```

model.py

```
class VinCasesAndCampaigns(models.Model):
    VIN = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    LatestOpenCaseID = models.DateField()
    LatestClosedCaseID = models.DateField()
    OpenDate = models.DateField()
    CloseDate = models.DateField()
    HasCampaigns = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    HasOpenCampaigns = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    HasCases = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    HasEstimates = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    HasDwell = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    HasClaims = models.BooleanField(default = False)

    exclude = ('id',)
```

Trace:

```
> Line number: 1 - u"Column 'id' not found in dataset. Available columns
> are: [u'VIN', u'LatestOpenCaseID', u'LatestClosedCaseID', u'OpenDate',
> u'CloseDate', u'HasCampaigns', u'HasOpenCampaigns', u'HasCases',
> u'HasEstimates', u'HasDwell', u'HasClaims']" Traceback (most recent
> call last): File
> "/Users/USER/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_import_export-0.2.8.dev0-py2.7.egg/import_export/resources.py",
> line 342, in import_data instance, new =
> self.get_or_init_instance(instance_loader, row)
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation

Comment: The indentation should be correct now.

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this problem by using the following steps:

**Step 1** first goto C:/Users/am.sa18/Desktop/myenv/Lib/site-packages/import_export/resources.py

**Step 2** open resources.py in the editor.

**Step 3** do change in line no 84, its looks like this

**Step 4** import_id_fields = ['id'] Where 'id' by-default set by import_export package,
you can change 'id' by your primary key of the model.
After adding primary key : import_id_fields = ['primary_key']

**Step 5** Save resources.py file and run the server.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example. I also used "exclude" and it works and no need to add exclude = ('id',) in models.py. 
My data set does not contain "id" field.

Python 2.7 | Django 1.11 | Django Import export 1.0.0 (2018-02-13)

Models.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.

class CourseList(models.Model):
    short_code = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    course_id = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True,blank=True,unique=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    count_current = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    count_cumulative = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    start_date = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    end_date = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    pacing_type = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    updated_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['end_date']

        def __unicode__(self):
            return self.title
```

resources.py

```
from import_export import resources, fields
from .models import CourseList

class CourseListResource(resources.ModelResource):
    status = fields.Field(column_name='availability', attribute="status")
    short_code = fields.Field(column_name='catalog_course', attribute="short_code")
    title = fields.Field(column_name='catalog_course_title', attribute="title")
    count_current = fields.Field(column_name='count', attribute="count_current")
    count_cumulative = fields.Field(column_name='cumulative_count', attribute="count_cumulative")


    class Meta:
        model = CourseList
        import_id_fields = ('course_id',)
        exclude = ('id', 'updated_date',)
        skip_unchanged = True
        fields = ('status', 'short_code','course_id', 'title', 'count_current', 'count_cumulative', 'end_date', 'pacing_type', 'start_date', )
```

admin.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.contrib import admin
from import_export.admin import ImportExportModelAdmin

# Register your models here.
from import_export import resources
from courselist.models import CourseList
from courselist.resources import CourseListResource


@admin.register(CourseList)
class CourseListAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    resource_class = CourseListResource
    list_display = ('id', 'course_id', 'title', 'start_date', 'end_date')
```

Answer (score 0):

Just **create an empty column** namely `id` before already created columns and then import the same file via Django import_export.

> Make sure `id` column should be of your first column in the CSV or Excel file

Answer (score -1):

include field id in the field of ModelResource

```
fields = ('id','VIN','LatestOpenCaseID','LatestClosedCaseID', 
              'OpenDate', 'CloseDate', 'HasCampaigns',)
```

and in your excel file add a column with filed id with empty values. this add a new field with autoincrement.

file.xls

```
id  VIN  OpenDate ...
    23   05-10-2018
    24   05-11-2018
```

Comment: I tried that before coming here but I still get the error if I let the column empty. Autoincrement seems not implemented

Answer (score -1):

admin.py should be:

```
class CourseListAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    resource_class = CourseListResource
    list_display = ('id', 'course_id', 'title', 'start_date', 'end_date')

admin.site.register(CourseList, CourseListAdmin)
```

I had the same issue with the decorator @admin.register. I probably followed the same old tutorial. See [Admin Integration](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#importing-data) in the real docs for django-import-export.