# django-import-export override not working

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-import-export

I am overriding the django-import-export resource's methods. But only parent methods are executed.

models.py

```
class Model(models.Model):
     modelField1  = models.CharField(
     modelField2...
     modelField3...
```

admin.py

```
class ModelResource(resources.ModelResource):

    def before_import(self, dataset, using_transactions, dry_run, **kwargs):
        print("INside BEfore IMport")
        dataset.headers = ('modelField1', 'modelField2', ...)
        del dataset[0]

    def get_instance(self, instance_loader, row):
        print("Inside get instance")
        return False

    def get_or_init_instance(self, instance_loader, row):
        print("INside Get or init")
        instance = self.get_instance(instance_loader, row)
        if instance:
            return (instance, False)
        else:
            return (self.init_instance(row), True)

@admin.register(Model)
class ModelAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    class Meta:
        model = MOdel
        resource_class = ModelResource
        list_display = ('modelField1', 'modelField2', ...)
        search_fields = ('modelField1', 'modelField2', ...)
```

I am not at all getting print statements in console. Error is thrown directly from the parent methods. They should not be executed at all. AM I right ?

```
 Line number: 1 - u"Column 'id' not found in dataset. Available columns are: [u'Col1', u'Col2', u'Col2', ...]"
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/aswin/projects/mastercityenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/import_export/resources.py", line 434, in import_row
instance, new = self.get_or_init_instance(instance_loader, row)
File "/home/aswin/projects/mastercityenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/import_export/resources.py", line 258, in get_or_init_instance
instance = self.get_instance(instance_loader, row)
File "/home/aswin/projects/mastercityenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/import_export/resources.py", line 252, in get_instance
return instance_loader.get_instance(row)
File "/home/aswin/projects/mastercityenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/import_export/instance_loaders.py", line 32, in get_instance
params[field.attribute] = field.clean(row)
File "/home/aswin/projects/mastercityenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/import_export/fields.py", line 63, in clean
list(data.keys())))
KeyError: u"Column 'id' not found in dataset. Available columns are: [u'Col1', u'Col2', u'Col2', ...]"
```

where column names in Excel document were "Col1", "Col2", ...

Question: So if you note the errors in the above code, they were from parent methods which I overloaded. Why are they executed? Shouldn.tmy code be executed printing the print lines in console ?

Comment: you are calling `ModelResource` instead of `ResourceClass` in your `ModelAdmin`

Comment: @PRMoureu sorry. that was a typo

Comment: Just check this working example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30512150/django-import-export-line-number-1-ucolumn-id-not-found/49668908#49668908

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [documentation](http://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#admin-integration), Nested `Meta` class is not required. So the Admin class should be like:

```
@admin.register(Model)
class ModelAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    resource_class = ModelResource
    list_display = ('modelField1', 'modelField2', ...)
    search_fields = ('modelField1', 'modelField2', ...)
```